# "issue" in inserting values in table

Tags: java, jdbc

I am making a program where I would read data from text files and store the in tables in mysql. In my files the data are as shown in the image: [image]

What the program have to do is, firstly the user give the directory, the program search for text files in it, then create a table with two fields (ID, NAME) and then insert the values in it. All the files have the same structure. The ID is in the third row and the name in the fifth row.

Could anyone help me with the query of inserting these values in the table? Where is the "error" in my code?
The code for my program is the below:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3808/mydb", "root", "root");

        String dirpath = "";
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please give the directory:");
            dirpath = scanner1.nextLine();
            File fl = new File(dirpath);
            if (fl.canRead())

                break;
            System.out.println("Error:Directory does not exists");
        }

        try {
            String files;
            File folder = new File(dirpath);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT")) {
                        List<File> txtFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
                        txtFiles.add(listOfFiles[i]);
                        String[] parts = files.split("\\.");
                        String tablename = parts[0];
                        DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) con
                                .getMetaData();
                        ResultSet rs = dm
                                .getTables(null, null, tablename, null);

                        if (!rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println("The table '" + tablename
                                    + "' just created. The data are:");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("The table '" + tablename
                                    + "' already exists.");
                            continue;

                        }

                        for (File txtFile : txtFiles) {
                            List sheetData = new ArrayList();

                            try {
                                FileReader in = new FileReader(txtFile);
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
                                String line = br.readLine();
                                while (line != null) {
                                    System.out.println(line);
                                    line = br.readLine();

                                }
                                in.close();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                            getCreateTable1(con, tablename);
                            {
                                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                        new FileReader((txtFile)));

                                String currentLine = br.readLine();
                                Map<Integer, String> Fields = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

                                while (currentLine != null) {
                                    String[] tokens = currentLine.split("\t");
                                    int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                                    String name = tokens[4];
                                    Fields.put(id, name);
                                    currentLine = br.readLine();
                                }

                            }
                            importData(con, txtFile, tablename);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

and the code for the function of importing is:

```
    private static String importData(Connection con, File txtFile,
            String tablename) {

        Map<Integer, String> Fields = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String all = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(Fields, ",");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " VALUES (" + all + ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Fill table...");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168108/how-get-values-for-table-from-specific-row-in-text-files

Comment: here it's about the function of inserting the values in tables.

Comment: then please reduce that wall of code and focus on that function

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is something going wrong in the query string you are creating. The values are integer and string, so make sure your string values is wrapped in single quotes. Try to debug the code or print the 'sql' variable.  Better will be to use PreparedStatement, which eliminates few such problems.

Answer (score 0):

you are using Statement which doesnot accept input parameters at run time use PreparedStatement instead

Comment: It doesnt work either with PreparedStatement.

Comment: @dedmar    where is the error log

Comment: When i am doing debug after the function which create the table when it reaches the line: int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]); it throws exception.

Comment: @dedmar seriously man focus on that function and exception it throws.........please post exception log also

Comment: I get this exception : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Comment: @dedmar your are taking your array to out of bound value check your code you array must be pointing to value which is not there................on which line this exception is coiming

Comment: could you help me how i will do it?

Comment: @dedmar I asked on which line you are getting this exception................I think this is your copy paste code

Comment: on  int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]); when it reads the next one  String name = tokens[4];

Comment: @dedmar initialize your token array outside the while loop first..............secondly your token array doesnot have any value in token[4] . and why are u putting static values in String name and int id

Comment: because in ID and name would be the two fields in every table that would be created.The data are in text files and all of them contains these.